# Python optional types before assertion

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am using Python type hints and mypy with the following code:

```py
from typing import Optional


def compute(
    use_wcog: bool = False,
    Xt: Optional[float] = None,
    Xd: Optional[float] = None,
    Xw: Optional[float] = None,
    Xs: Optional[float] = None,
):

    if use_wcog:
        reqs = (Xt, Xd, Xw)
        assert all([_ is not None for _ in reqs])
        res = ((Xt**2 + Xw**2) / Xd)**2
    else:
        reqs = (Xs, Xd)
        assert all([_ is not None for _ in reqs])
        res = (Xs**2 / Xd)**2

    return res
```

I get the following error:
Unsuported operand types for ** (float and None) (mypy error)

What is the proper way of handling it?

Comment: What version of mypy are you using? I can't reproduce with version 0.790 or 0.812. Also, there's no `*` character in your code. Are you sure you're running the same snippet through mypy as the one you posted?

Comment: I am sorry. My toy example was flawed. I have updated the snippet.

Comment: How is `Xd` optional if it is used in both cases in the division?

Comment: `Xd` is not necessarily optional. In any case this does not casuse the problem. I just did it for consistency and in case other formulas are implemented in the future.

Comment: The default argument of `None` for `Xd` does not make any sense if it is used unconditionally in a division. But apparently your problem is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mypy isn't quite clever enough to narrow the type based on `all` and the list comprehension.  Make it simple:

```
    if use_wcog:
        assert Xt and Xd and Xw
        res = ((Xt**2 + Xw**2) / Xd)**2
    else:
        assert Xs and Xd
        res = (Xs**2 / Xd)**2
```

FWIW, having these dependencies embedded in the body of the function makes typing largely useless IMO -- it's very easy to call this function in a way that will error at runtime, and the whole point of static typing is to make usage errors detectable statically.  Given that the two implementations of the function have completely different contracts with respect to what inputs are expected and what result is returned, I'd just make it two functions.

```
def compute_wcog(Xt: float, Xd: float, Xw: float) -> float:
    return ((Xt**2 + Xw**2) / Xd)**2

def compute_no_wcog(Xd: float, Xs: float) -> float:
    return (Xs**2 / Xd)**2
```

If you really need to have a single `compute` function with effectively multiple interfaces, you can use the `@overload` decorator:

```
from typing import Literal, Optional, overload

@overload
def compute(use_wcog: Literal[True], Xt: float, Xd: float, Xw: float, Xs: None) -> float: ...

@overload
def compute(use_wcog: Literal[False], Xt: None, Xd: float, Xw: None, Xs: float) -> float: ...

def compute(
    use_wcog: bool = False,
    Xt: Optional[float] = None,
    Xd: Optional[float] = None,
    Xw: Optional[float] = None,
    Xs: Optional[float] = None,
):
    assert Xd is not None

    if use_wcog:
        assert Xt is not None and Xw is not None
        res = ((Xt**2 + Xw**2) / Xd)**2
    else:
        assert Xs is not None
        res = (Xs**2 / Xd)**2

    return res

compute(True, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, None)    # works
compute(False, None, 1.0, None, 1.0)  # works
compute(True, None, 1.0, None, 1.0)   # error: No overload variant of "compute" matches argument types...
```

but this is obviously a lot more code for not a lot of gain.  :)

Comment: Is `Xt and Xd and Xw` safe enough or shall I use `Xt is not None and Xd is not None and Xw is not None`?

Comment: Ah, should probably be `is not None` given that floats can be zero.  Although a zero `Xd` at least will raise another exception.

Comment: I agree that the best is to have to separate functions. Thank you very much for providing the two perspectives.

Comment: Wow, I did not know the `overload` decorator. As you say, it may be overkill, but I am glad you mentioned it!