# Static type check within built-in function all for dict in python

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have the following dictionary:

```py
my_dict: Dict[str, int | None] = {}
```

I want check whether two specific keys are present in `my_dict` and if yes, update the value for one of these keys:

```py
if all(key in my_dict and my_dict[key] for key in ("key1", "key2")):
    my_dict["key1"] += my_dict["key2"]
```

`mypy` says it is an error:

```
test.py:4: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("int" and "None")  [operator]
test.py:4: error: Unsupported operand types for + ("None" and "int")  [operator]
test.py:4: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("None")  [operator]
```

My workaround of this issue:

```py
if (
    all(key in my_dict for key in ("key1", "key2"))
    and my_dict["key1"]
    and my_dict["key2"]
):
    my_dict["key1"] += my_dict["key2"]
```

which does not seem too nice. Can anyone please explain why the first option does not pass the type check?

Comment: I would say that type checkers have to draw the line somewhere and that seems to be one of those places. It's a tall order for them to understand that kind of complex type narrowing. I would just put a `# type: ignore[operator]` next to it and move on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python optional types before assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67008554/python-optional-types-before-assertion)

Comment: Without `mypy`, you don't need `in` at all - `bool(x in my_dict and my_dict[x])` is equivalent to `bool(my_dict.get(x))`. IMO for two keys `if my_dict.get(key1) and my_dict.get(key2)` reads better then the same with `all`, and it's a good case for `type: ignore[operator]`. You can use walrus for right side with `get`, but it won't solve lhs issue.

Comment: @SUTerliakov the linked question just confirms that `mypy` has issues narrowing types based on `all`. Thanks, @SUTerliakov and @DaniilFajnberg for the hints.